# conflicting types vs incompatible implicit declaration

Tags: c, gcc, function-declaration

The related C program is below：

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void testifbarisvisible();

    int main()
    {
            void bar(int);
        bar(1);
        testifbarisvisible();
    }

    void testifbarisvisible()
    {
        bar(2);
    }

    void bar(int x)
    {
        printf("functionbar\n");
    }
```

The output of gcc is:

```
% gcc -std=c99 -c /tmp/notfilescope.c
/tmp/notfilescope.c: In function ‘testifbarisvisible’:
/tmp/notfilescope.c:14:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘bar’
/tmp/notfilescope.c:7:7: note: previous declaration of ‘bar’ was here
/tmp/notfilescope.c:14:2: error: incompatible implicit declaration of function ‘bar’
/tmp/notfilescope.c:7:7: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘bar’ was here
```

After I removed the statement in line 7, the output is:

```
% gcc -std=c99 -c /tmp/notfilescope.c
/tmp/notfilescope.c: In function ‘main’:
/tmp/notfilescope.c:8:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘bar’
/tmp/notfilescope.c: At top level:
/tmp/notfilescope.c:17:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘bar’
/tmp/notfilescope.c:8:2: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘bar’ was here
```

The version of gcc is:

```
% gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

I'm confused about the difference between the two outputs of gcc.

This is from the gcc's documents, "Declarations of external variables and functions within a block apply only to the block containing the declaration.In other words, they have the same scope as any other declaration in the same place."

So I think that the function declaration in line 7 has no relationship with the function call in line 14. But the result indicate that opinion was wrong. They are all implicit declaration of function 'bar', but one of them leads to error (incompatible implicit declaration of function ‘bar’), and the other one leads to warning (conflicting types for ‘bar’), why?

This question has confused me a long time. Can someone help me?

Comment: There is no substantial difference between compiler errors and compiler warnings.

Comment: Why do you need bar declaration within other function? Just for fun?

Comment: @Roman Saveljev In the beginning, I just wanted to test if the declaration of external variables and functions in a block has block scope. Then I found the statements in gcc documents.

Comment: Just a note: C99 removed implicit function declarations, so both are invalid C99. gcc is fairly liberal in what code it accepts that it could reject by the standard (the standard requires a diagnostic, not abortion of compilation), if you want close standard conformance, use `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within main, bar has only function scope; it is known only within main. However, C has another process called *linkage*. Per C 1999 6.2.2 1, “An identifier declared in different scopes or in the same scope more than once can be made to refer to the same object or function by a process called linkage.”

In main, the declaration `void bar(int);` declares bar with external linkage, per C 1999 6.2.2 5: “If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier extern.”

Then, in testifbarisvisible, bar is not in scope. The statement `bar(2);` implicitly declares bar to be external, and, because bar is not in scope, it is an implicit declaration of bar with no prototype. This implicit declaration has a different type than the previous `void bar(int);`, but, because of linkage, it must refer to the same function. (Per 6.2.2 2, “In... an entire program, each declaration of a particular identifier with external linkage denotes the same object or function.”) This is a conflict, so the compiler produces an error.

When you remove `void bar(int);`, there is no explicit declaration of bar in main. Instead, bar is implicitly declaration by the following line, `bar(1);`. This implicit has the same type as the implicit declaration in testifbarisvisible. Because the declarations are identical, there is no error. The compiler still gives you a warning because implicit declarations are dangerous (because the eventual explicit declaration might be in a different file and might be different, which can cause undiagnosed errors at execution).

Comment: The definition of function is also a declaration. Why this declaration is not considered?

Comment: The definition of bar starting in line 17, `void bar(int x)`, is not visible earlier, where the implicit declaration appears in line 14. Only what is visible prior to that implicit declaration affects the declaration of bar at line 14.

Comment: Then, gcc will find another declaration of function 'bar' in line 17, and this declaration is incompatible with the declarations before. Why gcc not output an error but a warning? Is the declaration in a function definition less important?

Comment: Nice explanation. I'll try to keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: @junwanghe: I do not see a reason for the compiler not to give an error when it reaches the conflicting function definition. It might be a shortcoming of the compiler.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Perhaps, it's a shortcoming. But I believe more these different results are deliberately made by gcc. What's the rationale? By the way, your answer is the best. Thinks. My email is junwanghe@gmail.com. If you would resolve this question, contact me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the result you get is reasonable.

As soon as you write

```
void bar(int);
```

you are declaring that there is a function with that signature *somewhere* in this compilation unit and this is *not* an implicit declaration, it is explicit, if anything. But, as the documentation notes, this declaration does not escape the scope it is in, so when you get to

```
void testifbarisvisible()
{
    bar(2);
}
```

no such declaration is in scope, and the compiler complains.

Comment: so outside main, the bar function is implicitly declared: int return type, no assumptions about the parameter lists. So, why the error ?

Comment: I can only guess, but I'd say the compiler writers decided that the only sane way to handle what looks like a scoping mistake is to make it an error since the generated code in almost all cases will not do what the programmer wanted. I don't know what the C specification has to say about this but it might be something in it that motivates this too.

Comment: You haven't resolve my question. I'm not a native English speaker, so the question I asked is probably not very clear. If gcc do this deliberately, can we find the ralated statements in its documents？

Comment: This answer omits the fact that, although the scope of bar is within the function in which it is (implicitly) declared, it has external linkage and thus must refer to the same function as external declarations in other scopes. Since the compiler has seen an incompatible external declaration in another scope, there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of you code is that when you declare a **function prototype inside another function this mean that you want to call it only from this function** (the function is not visible outside).

In our case bar function is only visible inside `main`, not in the function `testifbarisvisible`, to make it visible to all your program the declaration must be done outside (like the way you declare global vars) or in a header file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void testifbarisvisible();

int main()
{
    void bar(int);  // bar can be use inside main, not outside
    bar(1);
    testifbarisvisible();
}

void testifbarisvisible()
{
    // void bar(int); // If you want to use it inside testifbarisvisible
    bar(2);
}

void bar(int x)
{
    printf("functionbar\n");
}
```

Comment: The fact that the scope of the identifier is limited to the function does not explain why the declaration in main conflicts with the declaration in testifbarisvisible.